# How to dynamically add row(s) in SQL query result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

this query

```
SELECT T.TestTypeId, F.FlockCode, AMT, CV, S.SampleDate 
FROM [dbo].[Tests] AS T 
JOIN [Samples] AS S ON T.SampleId = S.Id 
JOIN [TestTypes] AS TT ON T.TestTypeId = TT.Id 
JOIN [Flocks] AS F ON T.FlockId = F.Id 
WHERE T.TestTypeId = 7 AND T.IsDeleted = 0 
AND S.SampleDate BETWEEN '2017-12-17' AND '2018-01-08' 
AND T.FlockId IN (7,13)
ORDER BY S.SampleDate, F.FlockCode
```

returns the following result

```
TestTypeId  FlockCode   AMT     CV      SampleDate
7           R1.33       8.93    9.28    2017-12-17
7           R1.33       9.05    10.76   2018-01-01
7           R1.37       8.95    8.99    2018-01-01
```

which is accurate for the existing data, where for `S.SampleDate` 2017-12-17 there is only one row for`FlockCode` R1.33.

Now I need, to add another row in this result for the `FlockCode` R1.37 on the data 2017-12-17 with `0` or `null` `AMT` & `CV` value.

So the expected result would be

```
TestTypeId  FlockCode   AMT     CV      SampleDate
7           R1.33       8.93    9.28    2017-12-17
7           R1.37       0       0       2017-12-17
7           R1.33       9.05    10.76   2018-01-01
7           R1.37       8.95    8.99    2018-01-01
```

Any solution in either `SQL` or `LINQ` or `C#` will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic structure is to do this with a `cross join` and `left join`.  Your query is a bit complicated, so I would suggest:

```
with t as (
      SELECT T.TestTypeId, F.FlockCode, AMT, CV, S.SampleDate 
      FROM [dbo].[Tests] T JOIN
           [Samples] S
           ON T.SampleId = S.Id JOIN
           [TestTypes] TT
           ON T.TestTypeId = TT.Id  JOIN
           [Flocks] F
           ON T.FlockId = F.Id 
      WHERE T.TestTypeId = 7 AND T.IsDeleted = 0 AND
            S.SampleDate BETWEEN '2017-12-17' AND '2018-01-08' AND
            T.FlockId IN (7, 13)
     )
SELECT f.TestTypeId, f.FlockCode, COALESCE(t.AMT, 0) as AMT,
       COALESCE(t.CV, 0) as CV, d.SampleDate
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TestTypeId, FlockCode FROM t) f CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT SampleDate FROM t) d LEFT JOIN
     t
     ON f.FlockCode = t.FlockCode AND f.TestTypeId = t.TestTypeId,
        d.SampleDate = t.SampleDate
ORDER BY d.SampleDate, f.FlockCode;
```

Comment: ahh that's the ans i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL* you could use `UNION` operator

```
SELECT T.TestTypeId, F.FlockCode, AMT, CV, S.SampleDate 
FROM [dbo].[Tests] AS T 
JOIN [Samples] AS S ON T.SampleId = S.Id 
JOIN [TestTypes] AS TT ON T.TestTypeId = TT.Id 
JOIN [Flocks] AS F ON T.FlockId = F.Id 
WHERE T.TestTypeId = 7 AND T.IsDeleted = 0 
AND S.SampleDate BETWEEN '2017-12-17' AND '2018-01-08' 
AND T.FlockId IN (7,13)
UNION 
SELECT 7 AS TestTypeId, 'R1.37' AS FlockCode, 0 AS AMT, 0 AS CV, '2017-12-17' AS SampleDate
ORDER BY SampleDate, FlockCode
```

Comment: thanks for your ans, this fulfills the requirements but here `7` or `R1.37` will be dynamically changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just `UNION` it!

```
SELECT T.TestTypeId, F.FlockCode, AMT, CV, S.SampleDate 
FROM [dbo].[Tests] AS T 
JOIN [Samples] AS S ON T.SampleId = S.Id 
JOIN [TestTypes] AS TT ON T.TestTypeId = TT.Id 
JOIN [Flocks] AS F ON T.FlockId = F.Id 
WHERE T.TestTypeId = 7 AND T.IsDeleted = 0 
AND S.SampleDate BETWEEN '2017-12-17' AND '2018-01-08' 
AND T.FlockId IN (7,13)
UNION
SELECT 7 AS TestTypeId, 'R1.37' as FlockCode, 0 as AMT, 0 as CV, '2017-12-17' as SampleDate
ORDER BY SampleDate, FlockCode
```

Comment: thanks for your ans, this fulfills the requirements but here `7` or `R1.37` will be dynamically changed.